# All route query params are strings - typescript can't know to auto convert to required type

Tags: angular, string, typescript, types, numbers

This question is more a curiosity of mine.

I have an component from where I redirect to another, using an query parameter:

comp A:

```
 this.router.navigate(['dashboards'], {queryParams: {id: this.id}});
```

Even if my id have number type, I know the url is a string and the param will be converted automatically to string resulting in `domain.com/dashboards?id=23`

my question is about dashboards component, where I read this id:

```
id: number;

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {
   if (params.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
      this.id = Number(params.id); // here is the problem
   }
}

oneMethod(): void {
   if (typeof this.id !== 'undefined') {
      // if I can not convert the id received from queryParams to Number in constructor,
      // here I'll compare a number vs a string and will receive undefined result
      const dashboard = dashboards.find(x => x.id === this.id);
      this.selectedDashboardFormControl.setValue(dashboard);
   } else {
      this.selectedDashboardFormControl.setValue(dashboards[0]);
   }
}
```

I'm asking why I need to convert the value to `Number`, when I'm asigning it to `this.id` inside the constructor, if id is declared above as `number`.

So, a `number` type can accept a `string` type, if I don't convert it... is this an typescript bug?

Comment: params are string. just cast to number the typescript way `this.id = +params.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in other answer is that query parameters are strings and need to be casted to a number, if that is what you want. TypeScript does not actually know that what it is getting is in fact a string and not a number.

> I'm asking why I need to convert the value to Number, when I'm asigning it to this.id inside the constructor, if id is declared above as number.

What you need to know about TypeScript, is that it's there to help the developer during development. Your IDE will warn you, if you are trying to use wrong types in your code. We need to remember, that TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript during runtime and any typechecking is **NOT** run. TypeScript is just a superset of JavaScript and the intention is to make coding and debugging easier for you when the IDE will help you out :)

Comment: To be honest, I don't checked the warn list, maybe there is one for this problem. I'm very sure that IDE (IntelliJ) dosn't complain about this as an error, because it let me to `filter` ids (which are numbers) using a string, but surely the result will be empty or undefined (for `find`, as in my example)

Comment: If you **would** define params.id as a number, the compiler would trust you when you say it's a number, even though it is **not**. TypeScript just trusts that you are knowing the types and warn you if you are doing something that does not conform to your types. As mentioned on top, typescript does not know that it is a string, it just trusts that you know what you are doing :)

Comment: `Number` is actually a bad sample here, as `Number` accepts `any`. Instead try `parseFloat` and it will produce an error. So let's assume you have defined `params.id` as `number`, if you try to parseFloat it, it will error out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-msvw87?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts But as your code currently sits, params.id is of type any, thus no complaints: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6bhpku?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Your find will pass in the first sample even with a string, as TypeScript trusts that myVariable is a number: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ognk9z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Just to display the other opposite, if you would define params.id to be a string and trying to use find on a number array, this again will error out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5ap8bv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters are sent as strings. Therefore it needs to be casted to assign to a number type.